# corrupted double-linked list?

Tags: c++, operating-system

I am just debugging a big project and and getting this error

```
*** glibc detected *** p_appmanager/obj/appmanager: corrupted double-linked list: 0x08325e18 **
```

I have tried to debug the code with the valgrind, but I am not much familiar with this tool. So I am dumping the logs here if you can find out anything from them please let me know.

Can anyone explain what the following error message could mean?

```
==2181== Invalid read of size 1
==2181==    at 0x402C658: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==2181==    by 0x40FCC2D: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==2181==    by 0x4054D4B: start_thread (pthread_create.c:308)
==2181==    by 0x4269DDD: clone (clone.S:130)
==2181==  Address 0x4359234 is 12 bytes inside a block of size 21 free'd
==2181==    at 0x402ACFC: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==2181==    by 0x410899A: std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==2181==    by 0x4071B37: void std::_Destroy_aux<false>::__destroy<std::string*>(std::string*, std::string*) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x40717DC: void std::_Destroy<std::string*>(std::string*, std::string*) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x4071041: void std::_Destroy<std::string*, std::string>(std::string*, std::string*, std::allocator<std::string>&) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x407088A: std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >::~vector() (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x406F497: Parser::parse(std::string) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x40729E2: getMessage(int, Message**) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x804CB99: fifoThread(void*) (in /home/cleanhands/SBISSW (2)/p_appmanager/obj/appmanager)
==2181==    by 0x4054D4B: start_thread (pthread_create.c:308)
==2181==    by 0x4269DDD: clone (clone.S:130)
==2181== 
==2181== Invalid read of size 1
==2181==    at 0x402C663: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==2181==    by 0x40FCC2D: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==2181==    by 0x4054D4B: start_thread (pthread_create.c:308)
==2181==    by 0x4269DDD: clone (clone.S:130)
==2181==  Address 0x4359235 is 13 bytes inside a block of size 21 free'd
==2181==    at 0x402ACFC: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==2181==    by 0x410899A: std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==2181==    by 0x4071B37: void std::_Destroy_aux<false>::__destroy<std::string*>(std::string*, std::string*) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x40717DC: void std::_Destroy<std::string*>(std::string*, std::string*) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x4071041: void std::_Destroy<std::string*, std::string>(std::string*, std::string*, std::allocator<std::string>&) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x407088A: std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >::~vector() (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x406F497: Parser::parse(std::string) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x40729E2: getMessage(int, Message**) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x804CB99: fifoThread(void*) (in /home/cleanhands/SBISSW (2)/p_appmanager/obj/appmanager)
==2181==    by 0x4054D4B: start_thread (pthread_create.c:308)
==2181==    by 0x4269DDD: clone (clone.S:130)
==2181== 
==2181== Invalid read of size 4
==2181==    at 0x402DA08: memcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==2181==    by 0x4106850: std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::xsputn(char const*, int) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==2181==    by 0x40D8CDF: std::basic_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::xsputn(char const*, int) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==2181==    by 0x40FC9AA: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==2181==    by 0x40FCC3D: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==2181==    by 0x4054D4B: start_thread (pthread_create.c:308)
==2181==    by 0x4269DDD: clone (clone.S:130)
==2181==  Address 0x4359234 is 12 bytes inside a block of size 21 free'd
==2181==    at 0x402ACFC: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==2181==    by 0x410899A: std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==2181==    by 0x4071B37: void std::_Destroy_aux<false>::__destroy<std::string*>(std::string*, std::string*) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x40717DC: void std::_Destroy<std::string*>(std::string*, std::string*) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x4071041: void std::_Destroy<std::string*, std::string>(std::string*, std::string*, std::allocator<std::string>&) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x407088A: std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >::~vector() (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x406F497: Parser::parse(std::string) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x40729E2: getMessage(int, Message**) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x804CB99: fifoThread(void*) (in /home/cleanhands/SBISSW (2)/p_appmanager/obj/appmanager)
==2181==    by 0x4054D4B: start_thread (pthread_create.c:308)
==2181==    by 0x4269DDD: clone (clone.S:130)
==2181== 
==2181== Invalid read of size 2
==2181==    at 0x402DA60: memcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==2181==    by 0x4106850: std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::xsputn(char const*, int) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==2181==    by 0x40D8CDF: std::basic_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::xsputn(char const*, int) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==2181==    by 0x40FC9AA: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==2181==    by 0x40FCC3D: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==2181==    by 0x4054D4B: start_thread (pthread_create.c:308)
==2181==    by 0x4269DDD: clone (clone.S:130)
==2181==  Address 0x4359238 is 16 bytes inside a block of size 21 free'd
==2181==    at 0x402ACFC: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==2181==    by 0x410899A: std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==2181==    by 0x4071B37: void std::_Destroy_aux<false>::__destroy<std::string*>(std::string*, std::string*) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x40717DC: void std::_Destroy<std::string*>(std::string*, std::string*) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x4071041: void std::_Destroy<std::string*, std::string>(std::string*, std::string*, std::allocator<std::string>&) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x407088A: std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >::~vector() (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x406F497: Parser::parse(std::string) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x40729E2: getMessage(int, Message**) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x804CB99: fifoThread(void*) (in /home/cleanhands/SBISSW (2)/p_appmanager/obj/appmanager)
==2181==    by 0x4054D4B: start_thread (pthread_create.c:308)
==2181==    by 0x4269DDD: clone (clone.S:130)
==2181== 
==2181== Invalid read of size 1
==2181==    at 0x402DA90: memcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==2181==    by 0x4106850: std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::xsputn(char const*, int) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==2181==    by 0x40D8CDF: std::basic_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::xsputn(char const*, int) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==2181==    by 0x40FC9AA: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==2181==    by 0x40FCC3D: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==2181==    by 0x4054D4B: start_thread (pthread_create.c:308)
==2181==    by 0x4269DDD: clone (clone.S:130)
==2181==  Address 0x435923a is 18 bytes inside a block of size 21 free'd
==2181==    at 0x402ACFC: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==2181==    by 0x410899A: std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==2181==    by 0x4071B37: void std::_Destroy_aux<false>::__destroy<std::string*>(std::string*, std::string*) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x40717DC: void std::_Destroy<std::string*>(std::string*, std::string*) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x4071041: void std::_Destroy<std::string*, std::string>(std::string*, std::string*, std::allocator<std::string>&) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x407088A: std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >::~vector() (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x406F497: Parser::parse(std::string) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x40729E2: getMessage(int, Message**) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x804CB99: fifoThread(void*) (in /home/cleanhands/SBISSW (2)/p_appmanager/obj/appmanager)
==2181==    by 0x4054D4B: start_thread (pthread_create.c:308)
==2181==    by 0x4269DDD: clone (clone.S:130)
==2181== 
==2181== Invalid read of size 1
==2181==    at 0x402DA9C: memcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==2181==    by 0x4106850: std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::xsputn(char const*, int) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==2181==    by 0x40D8CDF: std::basic_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::xsputn(char const*, int) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==2181==    by 0x40FC9AA: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==2181==    by 0x40FCC3D: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==2181==    by 0x4054D4B: start_thread (pthread_create.c:308)
==2181==    by 0x4269DDD: clone (clone.S:130)
==2181==  Address 0x43f0936 is 14 bytes inside a block of size 21 free'd
==2181==    at 0x402ACFC: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==2181==    by 0x410899A: std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==2181==    by 0x4071B37: void std::_Destroy_aux<false>::__destroy<std::string*>(std::string*, std::string*) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x40717DC: void std::_Destroy<std::string*>(std::string*, std::string*) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x4071041: void std::_Destroy<std::string*, std::string>(std::string*, std::string*, std::allocator<std::string>&) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x407088A: std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >::~vector() (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x406F497: Parser::parse(std::string) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x40729E2: getMessage(int, Message**) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x804CB99: fifoThread(void*) (in /home/cleanhands/SBISSW (2)/p_appmanager/obj/appmanager)
==2181==    by 0x4054D4B: start_thread (pthread_create.c:308)
==2181==    by 0x4269DDD: clone (clone.S:130)
==2181== 
stop tablet
==2181== Invalid read of size 1
==2181==    at 0x402C658: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==2181==    by 0x4108EF1: std::string::operator=(char const*) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==2181==    by 0x4054D4B: start_thread (pthread_create.c:308)
==2181==    by 0x4269DDD: clone (clone.S:130)
==2181==  Address 0x45b2e14 is 12 bytes inside a block of size 21 free'd
==2181==    at 0x402ACFC: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==2181==    by 0x410899A: std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==2181==    by 0x4071B37: void std::_Destroy_aux<false>::__destroy<std::string*>(std::string*, std::string*) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x40717DC: void std::_Destroy<std::string*>(std::string*, std::string*) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x4071041: void std::_Destroy<std::string*, std::string>(std::string*, std::string*, std::allocator<std::string>&) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x407088A: std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >::~vector() (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x406F497: Parser::parse(std::string) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x40729E2: getMessage(int, Message**) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x804CB99: fifoThread(void*) (in /home/cleanhands/SBISSW (2)/p_appmanager/obj/appmanager)
==2181==    by 0x4054D4B: start_thread (pthread_create.c:308)
==2181==    by 0x4269DDD: clone (clone.S:130)
==2181== 
==2181== Invalid read of size 1
==2181==    at 0x402C663: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==2181==    by 0x4108EF1: std::string::operator=(char const*) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==2181==    by 0x4054D4B: start_thread (pthread_create.c:308)
==2181==    by 0x4269DDD: clone (clone.S:130)
==2181==  Address 0x45b2e15 is 13 bytes inside a block of size 21 free'd
==2181==    at 0x402ACFC: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==2181==    by 0x410899A: std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==2181==    by 0x4071B37: void std::_Destroy_aux<false>::__destroy<std::string*>(std::string*, std::string*) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x40717DC: void std::_Destroy<std::string*>(std::string*, std::string*) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x4071041: void std::_Destroy<std::string*, std::string>(std::string*, std::string*, std::allocator<std::string>&) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x407088A: std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >::~vector() (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x406F497: Parser::parse(std::string) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x40729E2: getMessage(int, Message**) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x804CB99: fifoThread(void*) (in /home/cleanhands/SBISSW (2)/p_appmanager/obj/appmanager)
==2181==    by 0x4054D4B: start_thread (pthread_create.c:308)
==2181==    by 0x4269DDD: clone (clone.S:130)
==2181== 
==2181== Invalid read of size 1
==2181==    at 0x402DAEA: memcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==2181==    by 0x4108C7A: std::string::_M_replace_safe(unsigned int, unsigned int, char const*, unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==2181==    by 0x4108CF8: std::string::assign(char const*, unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==2181==    by 0x4108F05: std::string::operator=(char const*) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==2181==    by 0x4054D4B: start_thread (pthread_create.c:308)
==2181==    by 0x4269DDD: clone (clone.S:130)
==2181==  Address 0x45b2e19 is 17 bytes inside a block of size 21 free'd
==2181==    at 0x402ACFC: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==2181==    by 0x410899A: std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==2181==    by 0x4071B37: void std::_Destroy_aux<false>::__destroy<std::string*>(std::string*, std::string*) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x40717DC: void std::_Destroy<std::string*>(std::string*, std::string*) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x4071041: void std::_Destroy<std::string*, std::string>(std::string*, std::string*, std::allocator<std::string>&) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x407088A: std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >::~vector() (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x406F497: Parser::parse(std::string) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x40729E2: getMessage(int, Message**) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x804CB99: fifoThread(void*) (in /home/cleanhands/SBISSW (2)/p_appmanager/obj/appmanager)
==2181==    by 0x4054D4B: start_thread (pthread_create.c:308)
==2181==    by 0x4269DDD: clone (clone.S:130)
==2181== 
==2181== Invalid read of size 4
==2181==    at 0x402DB18: memcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==2181==    by 0x4108C7A: std::string::_M_replace_safe(unsigned int, unsigned int, char const*, unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==2181==    by 0x4108CF8: std::string::assign(char const*, unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==2181==    by 0x4108F05: std::string::operator=(char const*) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==2181==    by 0x4054D4B: start_thread (pthread_create.c:308)
==2181==    by 0x4269DDD: clone (clone.S:130)
==2181==  Address 0x45b2e14 is 12 bytes inside a block of size 21 free'd
==2181==    at 0x402ACFC: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==2181==    by 0x410899A: std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==2181==    by 0x4071B37: void std::_Destroy_aux<false>::__destroy<std::string*>(std::string*, std::string*) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x40717DC: void std::_Destroy<std::string*>(std::string*, std::string*) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x4071041: void std::_Destroy<std::string*, std::string>(std::string*, std::string*, std::allocator<std::string>&) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x407088A: std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >::~vector() (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x406F497: Parser::parse(std::string) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x40729E2: getMessage(int, Message**) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x804CB99: fifoThread(void*) (in /home/cleanhands/SBISSW (2)/p_appmanager/obj/appmanager)
==2181==    by 0x4054D4B: start_thread (pthread_create.c:308)
==2181==    by 0x4269DDD: clone (clone.S:130)
==2181== 
Success:: tablet process terminated Successfully.
CONSOLE>start tablet
Success:: tablet Process Created Successfully
CONSOLE>stop tablet
==2181== Invalid read of size 4
==2181==    at 0x402DA08: memcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==2181==    by 0x4108C7A: std::string::_M_replace_safe(unsigned int, unsigned int, char const*, unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==2181==    by 0x4108CF8: std::string::assign(char const*, unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==2181==    by 0x4108F05: std::string::operator=(char const*) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==2181==    by 0x4054D4B: start_thread (pthread_create.c:308)
==2181==    by 0x4269DDD: clone (clone.S:130)
==2181==  Address 0x45dd8c4 is 12 bytes inside a block of size 21 free'd
==2181==    at 0x402ACFC: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==2181==    by 0x410899A: std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==2181==    by 0x4071B37: void std::_Destroy_aux<false>::__destroy<std::string*>(std::string*, std::string*) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x40717DC: void std::_Destroy<std::string*>(std::string*, std::string*) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x4071041: void std::_Destroy<std::string*, std::string>(std::string*, std::string*, std::allocator<std::string>&) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x407088A: std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >::~vector() (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x406F497: Parser::parse(std::string) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x40729E2: getMessage(int, Message**) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x804CB99: fifoThread(void*) (in /home/cleanhands/SBISSW (2)/p_appmanager/obj/appmanager)
==2181==    by 0x4054D4B: start_thread (pthread_create.c:308)
==2181==    by 0x4269DDD: clone (clone.S:130)
==2181== 
==2181== Invalid read of size 2
==2181==    at 0x402DA60: memcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==2181==    by 0x4108C7A: std::string::_M_replace_safe(unsigned int, unsigned int, char const*, unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==2181==    by 0x4108CF8: std::string::assign(char const*, unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==2181==    by 0x4108F05: std::string::operator=(char const*) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==2181==    by 0x4054D4B: start_thread (pthread_create.c:308)
==2181==    by 0x4269DDD: clone (clone.S:130)
==2181==  Address 0x45dd8c8 is 16 bytes inside a block of size 21 free'd
==2181==    at 0x402ACFC: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==2181==    by 0x410899A: std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==2181==    by 0x4071B37: void std::_Destroy_aux<false>::__destroy<std::string*>(std::string*, std::string*) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x40717DC: void std::_Destroy<std::string*>(std::string*, std::string*) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x4071041: void std::_Destroy<std::string*, std::string>(std::string*, std::string*, std::allocator<std::string>&) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x407088A: std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >::~vector() (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x406F497: Parser::parse(std::string) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x40729E2: getMessage(int, Message**) (in /usr/lib/libparser.so)
==2181==    by 0x804CB99: fifoThread(void*) (in /home/cleanhands/SBISSW (2)/p_appmanager/obj/appmanager)
==2181==    by 0x4054D4B: start_thread (pthread_create.c:308)
==2181==    by 0x4269DDD: clone (clone.S:130)
==2181==
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It looks like a thread is printing data (`char*` character data) that was already freed on the main (or another) thread.

More specificly, `Parser::parse` builds a `vector` of `std::string`s.

---

**EDIT** As requested in the comment, this is what I read, with ***[`highlights]`***:

> `==2181==` ***[`Invalid read of size 1`]***  
>   `==2181==`<sup>`at 0x402C658: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vg...`</sup> 
>   `==2181==`<sup>`by 0x40FCC2D: std::basic_ostream<char, std::c...`</sup> 
>   `==2181==`<sup>`by 0x4054D4B: start_thread (pthread_create.c:...`</sup> 
>   `==2181==`<sup>`by 0x4269DDD: clone (clone.S:130)`</sup> 
>   `==2181==` ***[`Address 0x4359234`]*** `is 12 bytes inside` ***[`a block of size 21 free'd`]***  
>   `==2181==`<sup>`at 0x402ACFC: operator delete(void*) (in /usr...`</sup> 
>   `==2181==`<sup>`by 0x410899A: std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(s...`</sup> 
>   `==2181==`<sup>`by 0x4071B37: void std::_Destroy_aux<false>::...`</sup> 
>   `==2181==`<sup>`by 0x40717DC: void std::_Destroy<std::string*...`</sup> 
>   `==2181==`<sup>`by 0x4071041: void std::_Destroy<std::string*...`</sup> 
>   `==2181==    by 0x407088A: std::vector<std::string, std::a...` ***[`::~vector()`]*** `(in /usr/lib/libparser.so` 
>   `==2181==    by 0x406F497:` ***[`Parser::parse(std::string)`]*** `(in /usr/lib/libparser.so` 
>   `==2181==`<sup>`by 0x40729E2: getMessage(int, Message**) (in ...`</sup> 
>   `==2181==`<sup>`by 0x804CB99: fifoThread(void*) (in /home/cle...`</sup> 
>   `==2181==`<sup>`by 0x4054D4B: start_thread (pthread_create.c:...`</sup> 
>   `==2181==`<sup>`by 0x4269DDD: clone (clone.S:130`</sup>

And I noticed the other backtracecs all highlighted the same pattern.

---

Apparently, some thread(s) get started, and they are passed references (in)to these strings. However, since the vector is local to `Parser::parse` (probably an automatic variable, or explicitely deleted), the references are no longer valid (*e.g. at the time the strings are being streamed using `std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream&, const char*)`*).

Sadly, the stack trace doesn't quite show what name/object module contains the offending line, but you can see it lives on a separate thread (due to the presence of `start_thread`)

**Edit** Apparently, the thread(s) take a *reference* to the `string`s (from the vector) because the thread is **also** trying to assign the strings to another `string`.

This might indicate that the programmer was aware of the fact that the refence was not reliable and tries to copy it to a thread-local variable. Maybe it's just that there's a race condition involved and the `string`s don't even live long enough for the local copy to work.

IOW. It would appear that a thread is being started as such:

```
#include <future>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// sample: return the largest integer value or 42
int some_background_worker(vector<string> const& ref_data)
{
    if (ref_data.empty()) return 42;

    vector<int> values(ref_data.size());
    transform(begin(ref_data), end(ref_data), begin(values), 
            [](string const& s) { return stoi(s); });
    return *max_element(begin(values), end(values));
}

struct Parser
{
    future<int> parse(string const& msg) const
    {
        istringstream iss(msg);
        istream_iterator<string> f(iss), l;

        const vector<string> data { f, l };

        // now dispatch a thread to do the work
        return async(some_background_worker, ref(data));
    }
};

int main() // mimicks your "fifoThread" function
{
    // we use a simple vector to stub your fifo queue:
    const std::vector<string> fifoQueue { "1 3 9 -1 2", "32389 3102 -34 -888", "-42 -889", "" };

    vector<future<int>> results;

    {
        Parser parser;
        for(auto& msg : fifoQueue)
            results.push_back(parser.parse(msg));
    }

    // all parser data has been throroughly destroyed, before we might even
    // start the workers
    for(auto& fut: results)
        std::cout << "result of worker: " << fut.get() << "\n";
}
```

Here, the same race condition occurs, as a reference to "soon-to-be-stale" data is passed to the thread:

```
async(some_background_worker, ref(data));
```

It crashes with `bad_alloc` on my system (which is bogus, but perfectly fine Undefined Behaviour).

Like I said above, the *std::string::assign* calls might indicate the thread attempts to copy the data locally, like:

```
vector<string> local_copy(ref_data);
```

But that will ***still*** be a *data race*, because (without explicit synchronization) there is no guarantee that `ref_data` is valid even at that point.

---

Fix it by *moving* the data into the thread instead:

```
int some_background_worker(vector<string> data);

// and then, in parse(...):
    async(some_background_worker, std::move(data));
```

Now, on my system, it runs and prints

```
result of worker: 9
result of worker: 32389
result of worker: -42
result of worker: 42
```

fully as expected. See it running **[live at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=e5e014ce02036db364a7df8f2b7d1f74-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51)**

Comment: Thank you very much. You have pinpointed the exact location where the corruption is occurring. 
"More specificly, Parser::parse builds a vector of std::strings."

Comment: but what makes you say that, I mean can you electorate those message to me so that next time I don't need your help.

Comment: @AmitBhaira I've edited the answer showing how I read the backtraces, with ***[`highlights`]*** showing the things that trigger my analysis. So, in fairness, it was valgrind pinpointing the source of the corruption :)

Comment: agree, but to read valgrind's output also require another set of skills , so thanks number 2 :)