# Is it possible to have two boost acceptors in the same program?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

My boost server accidentally stopped accepting incoming connections because some other guy from my team created yet another server using boost acceptor in a different thread (using different port)? Is it normal and how make them two servers work independently and not messing with each other?

SOLVED: acceptors had nothing to do with it, the guy started an infinite loop somewhere that blocked other components. I guess that is what happens when the team is working uncoordinated :( Sorry guys, sehe's the best as always

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the root cause of the problem was elsewhere

Comment: To be fair, this kind of post is uncannily useful in a serendipitous way. Often the things that trip up one project also creep up in another. A good example of it would be [this kind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17899508/corrupted-double-linked-list/17899692#17899692) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124489/unix-sort-command-takes-much-longer-depending-on-where-it-is-executed-fastest/7150015#7150015). I think your question is fine for SO. (Not even mentioning hangups like [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9207954/visual-studio-find-in-files/9208041#9208041))

Answer (score 5):

We're using multiple acceptors with a single io_service just fine, as by design.

Also, we're sharing out work across multiple *other* io_service instances, using the same sockets, just fine, as by design.

What could be happening in your code base would be antipatterns: if people call `stop()` on your `io_service` instance then yes that would wreak havoc on any other async operations also queued on the same instance.

So, in general, the idea would be to avoid using `stop()` or similar "life-time" operations on a shared `io_service` instance. The only appropriate time for such a call would be during a *forced shutdown sequence*, but really graceful shutdown should let all active connections shutdown and the pending work to be drained, so that threads running `io_service::run` would spontaneously complete anyways.

See also:

- [Why would we need many acceptors in the Boost.ASIO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44484689/why-would-we-need-many-acceptors-in-the-boost-asio/44485523#44485523)
- [How to design proper release of a boost::asio socket or wrapper thereof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43239208/how-to-design-proper-release-of-a-boostasio-socket-or-wrapper-thereof/43243314#43243314)

Comment: @theshmoo since you asked nicely on the now-deleted answer: added links to samples. Especially the last link has an elaborate sample setup that also goes into  detail about graceful shutdown